# log4net How do I set the log level for a specific assembly?

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using a third-party assembly that utilizes log4net. The assembly in question logs too often to the "Info" log level. This causes a lot of noise for my application that I do not want.

Is there a way that I can configure a different log level for a specific assembly?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, sort of.
There is a way to set value based on the logger name from within the config file. I'm leaving out the rest of the file for ease, but in your file you should have a root section like below.

Now I just add the extra section for the other logger.

For example:

```
<root>        
    <level value="ERROR" />    
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>    
<logger name="ServiceLib">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>  
</logger>
```

This works if you are creating a logger by passing the type. The name is then based on the namespace of the class.
Like this:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ServiceLib.MyWebService));
```

Hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

You cannot do it for an assembly but can for the packages in that assembly. So, if that assembly packages all all start with Com.Foo, the configuration that follows will do what you want and restrict logging to WARN level and above, so INFO logging will not appear.

```
<log4net>
    <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
    <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">

        <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <!-- Print the date in ISO 8601 format -->
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="A1" />
    </root>

    <!-- Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package Com.Foo -->
    <logger name="Com.Foo">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

If the Lib you use does not follow this convention (logging based on type name), you must check in you logging file what is the string the Lib uses for logging and change the "Com.Foo" for that string.